# Syntax error, unrecognized expression "path". Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, angular4-router

I want to use routerLink with value from a property in my component and I got an error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>       /configuration/reservations
>       at Function.Sizzle.error (scripts.bundle.js:1581)
>       at Sizzle.tokenize (scripts.bundle.js:2233)
>       at Sizzle.select (scripts.bundle.js:2660)
>       at Function.Sizzle [as find] (scripts.bundle.js:885)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.find (scripts.bundle.js:2923)
>       at new jQuery.fn.init (scripts.bundle.js:3033)
>       at jQuery (scripts.bundle.js:99)
>       at getTargetFromTrigger (scripts.bundle.js:10955)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (scripts.bundle.js:10997)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (scripts.bundle.js:5207)

My Code:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainSidebar" class="mainSidebar" routerLink='{{menuItem.subItems[0].path}}'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this `[routerLink]="[menuItem.subItems[0].path]"`.

**Happy Coding**

Comment: I forgat to specify..the app work. Router redirect me correct.

Comment: If my answer helped you. Please mark it as an answer and vote it.:)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution..

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainSidebar" class="mainSidebar" (click)="navigateToRoute(menuItem)">
```

and in my component:

```
  protected navigateToRoute(item: IMenuItem) {
    this.router.navigate([item.subItems[0].path]);
  }
```

Now work. Thank you !